# Accessing controls from implementation class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I develop a game that has a big number of buttons (25).

I want to know if i can access them without initiating them in interface (.h) in my implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set their tag value, and use the `viewWithTag:` method on their `superview` to retrieve individual buttons.